# Ayuda con Matriz dinámica en C

Tags: c, array

Debo crear un tablero cuadrado de juego dónde le pida al usuario de qué tamaño lo quiere con memoria dinámica, intenté hacerlo pero al compilar, luego de pedir el número, el programa se cierra y no aparece la tabla.

Aquí está mi código hasta ahora.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int i,j,halfsize,cont=48,size;

char **Array;

printf("%cDe qu%c tama%co quiere que sea el tablero?\n",168,130,164);
scanf("%d",&size);


Array=(char **)malloc(size*sizeof(int *));

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    Array[i]=(char **)malloc(size*sizeof(int *));
}


halfsize=(size+1)/2;
//printf("la mitad es %d\n",halfsize);


for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        Array[i][j]=' ';
    }
}

Array[1][halfsize-1]='X';

Array[size][halfsize-1]='O';


for(i=0;i<size+1;i++)
{
    Array[0][i-1]=cont;

    cont++;
}


for(i=0;i<size+1;i++)
{
    printf("%d",i);

    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
    {

        printf("|%c",Array[i][j]);

    }
 printf("|");    
 printf("\n");

}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

De forma concretara, ¿Qué es lo que debe hacer el código según el ejercicio?

Fíjate en la linea:

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
```

El `8` se debe fijar de una manera dinámica, de lo contrario, estarías escribiendo fuera de la matriz si la misma fuera dimensionada menor a `9`, si es mayor a nueve no vas a poder escribir la matriz completa.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Tu respuesta debería redactarse en mejor manera. La pregunta del inicio es más indicada para publicarse como comentario de la pregunta y para el resto de la pregunta, te recomendaría que incluyeras referencia a otros sitios en internet donde ayuden a complementar tu respuesta. Te recomiendo que leas este artículo: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).